# How do I allow an empty result in my filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I filter the elements of an array using this function:

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
            return obj[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
}
var newarr = filter(arr, { desc: dv, aasc: av, rev: cv, flo: acv });
```

However, if the user doesn't input anything, then the results will return nothing. I am trying to code it so that if they choose nothing for that specific criteria, then it won't filter it.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "it won't filter it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not getting it, but wouldn't you just check for empty values

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
            return !(criteria[c]) || obj[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You got it! I can't believe I couldn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: The question might have been phrased slightly better :( well done adeneo !

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to code it so that if they choose nothing for that specific criteria, then it won't filter it.

Then do that. Get the filters as an object from user inputs, or `null` if no filters are provided then just do something, like this:

```
var userFilters = ... // get filters
var newarr = userFilters ? filter(arr, userFilters) : arr;
```

If for some reason this doesn't work for you, you could always rewrite your `filter` method like this:

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
    if (criteria)
        return arr.filter(function(obj) {
            return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
                return obj[c] == criteria[c];
            });
        });
    else
        return arr;
}
```

---

However, from your comments, it seems like what you mean is simply that if a value is not provided, you'd like to not apply that filter, but that other filters would still apply. In that case your current code works, just change how you're generating the filters object:

```
var userFilters = {};
if (dv) userFilters[desc] = dv;
if (av) userFilters[aasc] = av;
if (cv) userFilters[rev] = cv;
if (acv) userFilters[flo] = acv;
var newarr = filter(arr, userFilters);
```

This works because it only adds elements to the filter collection when they're specified. If no items are added, the then `arr` is returned unmodified.

Comment: The former suggestion did not work:
`var userFilters = [{ desc: dv, aasc: av, rev: cv, flo: acv }];`
`var newarr = userFilters ? filter(arr, userFilters) : arr;`

The latter suggestion works, but if they do not input any one of the criteria, then it will display every single result possible and ignore the other criteria.

Comment: @ChrisRockGM Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. See my updated answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the criteria for any value ?

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
if(criteria)
{
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function(c) {
            return obj[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
}
else
{
  return error of some kind. 
}
}
```

Or you could add a check for null input on the filter input...

Comment: I doesn't check each individual criteria. I am trying to figure out how to filter only criteria that the user has inputted and ignore the criteria that the user has not entered.

Comment: so on your else you can perform another action to not show anything, even add a dom element to say you have not requested anything.. Criteria is their input.. You have the data to work with...